# How do I ask an input from a user and analyse the input as the user types it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a particular program in python that requires an input from the user but that input has to be simultaneously analyzed as the user types. 
 
 **How do I achieve this?** 
**The user specifies the input through the command line.**

Comment: Could you please specify your question? Is the input done via command line or a gui?

Comment: Simultaneously, is a notion really particular. Why you can't wait until user have put its all input?

Comment: I'm trying to build a program that tracks the typing speed of the user. My plan is to detect the mistyped words by the user. Hence, I need to analyse the data simultaneously.

Comment: What do you mean by `command line`?  Normally that refers to the strings that follow the script name when starting a Python session - strings which are processed by the shell and given to the script.

Comment: Normally a Python script accepts user input via the `input` function, which returns at the end of the line, not character by character.  There's probably a way of accepting characters one at a time by looking at `sys.stdin`, but I haven't explored that.

Comment: Try using pynput to get key presses, and just echo back whatever the user enters, so it has the effect of using `input()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows you can get the input from the user using `msvcrt.getch()` instead of `input()`. This way you can process the input as it is being typed.

```
import msvcrt

def process_key(key):
    # ADD YOUR CODE
    print("processed:", key)

while True:
    key = msvcrt.getch()
    process_key(key)
```

On Linux you can use [getch](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) in a similar way.